# MATLAB GUI Look and Feel

Tags: user-interface, matlab

Is there any way to change the look and feel of MATLAB GUI? I want to change the look and feel of MATLAB as done in Java.

Answer (score 5):

Of course this is possible: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/modifying-matlab-look-and-feel/